# Firebase Unity plug-in: How do you persist user session? (auto sign in)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using the email-password user authorization and trying to implement a "remember me" function, and so far have no luck whatsoever.

I've tried the token pattern (email-pass signin --> request firebase token --> store token, and then replay the token back to the server using `SignInWithCustomTokenAsync()` when the user opens the game again), but it failed every time with exception message

> The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.

So my question is, if Firebase tokens are considered malformed by Firebase (it is a valid JWT, I checked), then how do you persist user session?

Sure, I can store the user email and password in `playerprefs` or whatever, but that is such a bad security practice, I wouldn't touch it with a 10 foot pole.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but Firebase actually stores the user between sessions. You could say that the "Remember Me" is built in by default. You should have a listener attached to `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.StateChanged` and it'll automatically be called once the initialization has finished. If `StateChanged` gets called and `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser != null` then you're signed in and can automatically skip the sign in screen.

I don't know if this is best practice or not, but I generally have a "Logging in..." prompt at the beginning of my projects that lasts for 10 seconds before showing the login screen. Obviously the 10 seconds ends early (usually within 1 second) if `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.StateChanged` prompts a login.

Comment: The event never seems to fire upon initialization when running the game in Unity Editor. Do you know if it should, or if this whole "persist authentication session" is limited to running on iOS or Android devices?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know(I'm no expert) you cannot create tokens through the Unity SDK. You will need to run the Admin SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), generate them with that and send them to the client. The TokenAsync function in the SDK only generates an ID token. Not an access token.

However, I implemented a solution based on this a few days ago only to find out that the custom tokens generated by the Admin SDK have an expiration time limited to 3600seconds(1hour). Which is quite short and ultimately it didn't really help me auto-login users if they had suffered from a crash or just terminated the app.

I would have loved to be able to customize the custom tokens more so I could set longer expiration times and whatnot.